# String matching in Jquery

Tags: jquery, list

My page has a textbox.User will enter a one character in it.That character i have to match with the list item values and if match occur all values will be printed.Suppose user enter "T",then all list items starting with "T" will be printed.

This is Html code.

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="text1"  class="cal" />
<input type="button" value="calculate" id="Button2" />
```

This is JQuery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calculate").click(function() {
        var getsValue = $("#textbox1").val();
        $("ul > li").each(function() {
            if (getsValue == $(this).text()) {
                "print here"
            }
            else {
                alert("no")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It is working if i enter whole string but i need to enter only one character.
  Please help.
  Thank you.

Comment: use `$(this).text().indexOf(getValue) != -1`

Comment: use `keyup()` function instead of click http://api.jquery.com/keyup/ do you want full code??

Comment: @run
Please if it is possible.

Comment: There're a lot of error in that questions. Like `$("#calculate")`does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textbox1").on("keyup", function() {
        var getsValue = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

        $("ul > li").each(function() {
            if (getsValue == $(this).text().charAt(0)) {
                document.write( $(this).text() );
            }
            else {
                alert("no")
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNc9Q/)

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
  if (getsValue == $(this).text()) {
                "print here"
    }
```

as

```
   if ($(this).text().indexOf(getsValue)==0) {
            "print here"
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your rectified code..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#Button2").click(function() {
       var Arr=[];
        $('li').each(function(){Arr.push($(this).html());});
        var textValue=$('#text1').val();
        Arr=$.grep(Arr,function(n){return (n.substring(0,1))==textValue;});
        alert(Arr);
    });

});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nw7xk/)

​

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#text1").keyup(function () {

         $("ul > li").each(function () {             
                if($("#text1").val() == $(this).text().charAt(0)) {
                    $("#text1").val($(this).text());
                }


         });
        });


});
```

YOU can add uppercase lowercase conversion